# Access calculates date but sql is making it null?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ms-access, vba

I have an access query that takes start and stop and returns runtime in minutes then based on the runtime in mins the run time in hour is calculated:

The part of access query used to retrieve the below results are:

```
 [Net Weight Tracking].[Start Time], [Net Weight Tracking].[Stop Time], 
    Hour([start time]) AS HrStart, Hour([stop time]) AS HrStop, 
    [date] & " " & [start time] AS Start,
     IIf([hrstart]>12 And [hrstop]<12,[date]+1 & " " & [stop time],[date] & " " & [stop time]) AS Stop, 
    DateDiff("n",[start],[stop]) AS [Runtime (Min)], 
    [runtime (Min)]/60 AS [Runtime (Hrs)]
```

[image]

But on my SQL Server Side:

The Query i use to retrieve the same info for sql is:

```
  SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Date, [Unit UPC Base Item], [Item (Optional)], [Preset Number], [Product Group], [Product Group Description], 
    Shift, [Rotation Code],BBD,
    [Operator Name], Supervisor, [Production Line],  
    [Production Line Description], [Bagger Number], StartTime, 
    StopTime, HrStart, HrStop,
    Start, Stop, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Start, Stop) AS [RunTime Mins], 
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Start, Stop) / 60.0 AS [RunTime Hrs]
 FROM (SELECT StartTime, StopTime, HrStart,HrStop, Start, 
    DATEADD(DAY, CASE WHEN HrStart > 12 AND HrStop < 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, Stop) 
    AS Stop 
FROM (SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(TIME, dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Start Time]), 5) 
AS StartTime, 
LEFT(CONVERT(TIME, dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Stop Time]), 5) AS StopTime, 
DATEPART(HOUR, dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Start Time]) AS HrStart, 
DATEPART(HOUR, dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Stop Time]) AS HrStop, 
DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, CONVERT(TIME, dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Start Time])), dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].Date) AS Start, 
DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, CONVERT(TIME, dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].[Stop Time])), dbo.[Net Weight Tracking].Date) 
AS Stop
```

[image]

i wonder how is access able to get the runtime in hrs?? plz help??

Comment: First, Access indeed does use SQL (as shown by your own code) so to say 'on my SQL side' is misleading. SQL is a declarative programming language not restricted to any one application/software. Thanks to your keywords, I understood you meant SQL Server but note this may not be obvious to current and future readers.

Comment: @Parfait you are correct and i have now posted the entire code in the question, only this row is causing the error in total, there is a difference of 5.28, all the other rows are the same, that is why i am more confused?? plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query seems fine to me and if this is the only row that is giving u an error, then may be there was an error when trying to update your Stop time, so what i would do is try to manually update the STOP to 10/7/2013 and see if that fixes your issue, my guess is since the stop time is null, it evaluates your query to the below:

```
Start, Stop, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Start, null) AS [RunTime Mins], 
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Start, null) / 60.0 AS [RunTime Hrs]
```

the result of the above is null that is the reason all 3 other columns are null:

RunTimeMins, RunTimeHrs, Stop Time is null because it gets derived from Stop

Comment: your right the upsize wizard from access must have screwed it up, it is working the totals are all tallying up correctly, appreciate the help bud

Answer (score 1):

In the Access query, `[Stop]` (used in `[Runtime (Min)]` is derived from an `IIF()` function which is simply the MS Access function for if/then/else. In order to reproduce the same result, you need to replicate this if/then/else in SQL Server which is not shown above.

Furthermore, SQL Server's corresponding IF function is the [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) function where you insert the condition in a `WHEN` clause and apply it to a `THEN` clause and for its false outcome in an `ELSE` clause. Aside, SQL Server 2012 does use the [IIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) function.

Also be aware in SQL Server you cannot reference an alias of a calculated column in the same query, meaning unlike the Access query you will have to re-write out the other formulas used in a particular expression.

Comment: appreciate the help, it was my mistake for not posting the entire query it was just too big of a messy query but its all good now issue resolved :) vote up for getting back soo fast